# Make git follow symlinks (or an alternative to solve the same problem)

Tags: git, symlink

I've seen this question asked here a couple of times already, but all the answers look outdated or don't work for my use case (like making the symlink go the other way around or using a hardlink).

Here's what's going on:

I have some code running on a server and use git to keep it updated. The code requires some image files to work, which change/increase over time. I use LFS to push them to the repo.

My issue is, that I would like these images to live in my image folder on an external drive where the rest of my media is and use a symlink, so the code can still acces them, as if they were somewhere in its root directory.

Is there a way to make git follow the symlink and treat it as a folder, so I can push all the images I need to the server?

Alternatively I am open to suggestions that solve the same problem in a different way.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: @bk2204 The server runs Ubuntu and I develop mostly Ubuntu and very rarely on Windows